# Robotframework, firefox doesn't open right, webdriverexception

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, selenium-firefoxdriver

I try to make a script running with robotframework but it won't work.

- robotframework 3.0.2
- selenium2library 3.0.0
- firefox 56 & 57
- python 3.5.2 & python 2.7.9
- Geckodriver 0.19.1 (installed in path)
- windows 10 pro

EDIT:
python 2.7.9 met chromedriver works like a charm!

My script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${SERVER}         localhost:7272
${BROWSER}        Firefox
${PROFILE}        C:\\Users\\Kees\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\89res77i.default
${VALID USER}     demo
${VALID PASSWORD}    mode
${LOGIN URL}      http://${SERVER}/
${WELCOME URL}    http://${SERVER}/welcome.html
${ERROR URL}      http://${SERVER}/error.html

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    Open Browser To Login Page
    Login Page Should Be Open    

*** Keywords ***

Open Browser To Login Page
    Open Browser    ${LOGIN URL}    ${BROWSER}    ff_profile_dir=${PROFILE}
    Maximize Browser Window
    Set Selenium Speed    ${DELAY}
    Login Page Should Be Open

Login Page Should Be Open
    Title Should Be    Login Page
```

If I run this, a new window of firefox opens and I get this error:
[image]
And firefox does seem weird to me:
[image]
I haven't seen that picture before even so the orange color..

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Just a few questions. Which version of Geckodriver are you running? Is Geckodriver in your (windows) `%PATH%`?  Which version of Selenium (Python) are you running? Is it [higher then version](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver#selenium) 3.5? Have you tried to use Python 2.7.x as well?

Comment: selenium2library still does not support py3 - it is in the works, but not officically out yet. I do not know is this the cause of your problem, but wanted to give you a warning you'll hit various issues with this setup.

Comment: @A.Kootstra:
I edited the post. Geckodriver 0.19.1, placed in path. Selenium 3.7.0.
I haven't tried python 2.7 cause I need 3.x for some other scripts. Is it easy to have both running side by side?

Comment: @Todor:
O, I thought it was already done, that's a shame. Thanks for the warning!

Comment: It is not hard to run side by side. Most Python enthousiasts will have several  versions running in parallel.

Comment: Allright, I tried to run it with python 2.7.9.
first I installed robotframework and selenium2library. Unfortunatelly nothing changed.